# Elusive MATLAB built-in function

Tags: matlab, function, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, built-in

I am trying to read the following internal MATLAB function:

```
>>which visionInitializeAndExpandCheckerboard
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\toolbox\vision\vision\visionInitializeAndExpandCheckerboard)
```

But it appears to be hidden away! And very well hidden.

None of the following methods to access it have worked:

- Highlighting the name and pressing Ctrl+D.
- Typing "edit visionInitializeAndExpandCheckerboard" in the command line.
- Searching for the file in Matlab's own FindFiles.
- Searching for the file on the disk.
- Trying to Step Into the function in debug mode (I just get the output as if I had requested Step Out instead).

Btw, the reason I am looking into this is that the parent function **detectCheckerboardPoints** has seriously declined in performance from R2015a to R2016b and I am trying to figure out why.

Comment: So built-in means that you won't be able to find a `.m` file because it is likely implemented as a mex file.

Comment: @Suever Indeed. But if it's a mex, then at least a binary file would be lying somewhere on the disk (and often the binary built-ins do have an .m wrapper with internal documentation) - here it seems like a complete vanishing act.

Comment: It won't necessarily be it's own file. It is likely bundled into a library. Did you try using `grep` to look for references to it?

Comment: @Suever I am using windows so I tried windows' search - to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

The internal function is compiled native code, so you will not be able to see its source. If you see a performance degradation, you should call Mathworks tech support and complain. If it is something they can fix, they will send you a patch, and fix it in the next release.